# How to add components to list dynamically in React with no redundant render?

Tags: reactjs

[Here is an online sample.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLdaGo)

```
var FruitList = React.createClass({
      render : function() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <ul className="list-group text-center">
              {
                Object.keys(this.props.fruits).map(function(key) {
                  count = count + 1;
                  return <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-info">{this.props.fruits[key]+count}</li>
                }.bind(this))
              }
            </ul>
           </div>
         );
       }
     });
```

I want to add "Cherry" to list.
[image: before]

As is, it redraws all items redundantly. I hope that orange1 and apple2 need to keep their state with no redraw redundantly.

What the design for dynamic list components is better? 
[image: after]

Comment: add key props. read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys. heres your example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGJPPz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract your list item into it's own pure component, make sure the props only change when the data actually changes, and use the `key` prop to let react know which item in the list. This way the list will re-render, but the child `FruitItem` will only re-render when the props change.

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
```

-

```
class FruitItem extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('FruitItem render', this.props.name);
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
        {this.props.name}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

-

```
Object.keys(this.props.fruits).map((key) => {
  return (
    <FruitItem
      key={key}
      name={this.props.fruits[key]}
    />
  );
})
```

See [working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqyZoW?editors=1111), check the console to watch for re-renders

Comment: Thank you Austin, That's all I wanted